# Sequelize don't write data as expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js, next.js

In a **Next.js** context, I'm trying to insert a data in a table using this code snippet :

```js
const user = new User();
user.firstname = "John";
user.lastname = "Appleseed";
user.email = "john.appleseed@apple.com";
await user.create()
```

But when I inspect the log here's what I see [image: Log from create User]

Basically, the data I put in the request are not written on the DB, but in a certain way Sequelize receive it (as shown in `_previousData`). But I don't know why there are moved from `dataValues` to theses `_previousData`

Here are the model I'm using

The core model :

```js
export default class User {

    id!: bigint
    hash!: string
    firstname?: string
    lastname?: string
    email?: string
    isValidated?: boolean = false
   
    async create(): Promise<void> {

        try {

            await UserEntity.create({
                accountValidated: false,
                firstname: this.firstname,
                lastname: this.lastname,
                email: this.email
            });

        } catch (error) {
            console.error('User.create', error.message)
            throw error
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the entity related to Sequelize and my PG

```js
interface UserAttributes {
    id?: bigint
    hash?: string
    firstname?: string
    lastname?: string
    email?: string
    accountValidated: boolean
}

interface UserCreationAttributes extends Optional<UserAttributes, "id"> {}

export default class UserEntity extends Model<UserAttributes, UserCreationAttributes> implements UserAttributes {

    public id!: bigint
    public hash!: string
    public firstname?: string
    public lastname?: string
    public email?: string
    public accountValidated!: boolean
    public readonly createdAt!: Date
    public readonly updatedAt!: Date

    public readonly accounts?: AccountEntity[]; // Note this is optional since it's only populated when explicitly requested in code

    public static associations: {
        accounts: Association<UserEntity, AccountEntity>;
    };

}

UserEntity.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        unique: true
    },
    hash: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    },
    firstname: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    lastname: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            isEmail: {
                msg: "This email is malformed"
            }
        }
    },
    accountValidated: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
    },

}, {
    sequelize, // We need to pass the connection instance
    modelName: 'User',
    underscored: true,
    tableName: 'blk_user',
    timestamps: true
})

UserEntity.beforeValidate(user => {
    user.hash = `usr_${v4()}`
})

UserEntity.beforeCreate(instance => console.log('beforeCreate', instance))
```

What I've tried

- [x] Comment hooks
- [x] Comment associations

## EDIT 11/16 6:39 CET

Seems that it is linked to my way of declaring my models TS interfaces and models. I'll dig into it

Comment: Did you look at a result value from `create`?

Comment: Just checked now, 
"createResult": {
    "id": "8",
    "accountValidated": false,
    "firstname": null,
    "lastname": null,
    "email": null,
    "hash": "usr_3ec34b36-6900-4b10-af30-c6443764fdba",
    "createdAt": "2020-11-15T12:28:36.637Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-11-15T12:28:36.637Z"
  }

Comment: Check something like `attributes` or `rawAttributes` in UserEntity just before `create` call

Comment: Not sure what you mean as `create` is a static method.
 I've tried this : 


const userEntity = UserEntity.build({
                accountValidated: false,
                firstname: this.firstname,
                lastname: this.lastname,
                email: this.email
            })

console.log('_attributes', userEntity._attributes)
console.log('_creationAttributes', userEntity._creationAttributes)

Both are `undefined` :'(

Comment: I mean to look at static model UserEntity before calling `create`

Comment: Sorry @Anatoly it doesn't ring a bell in my mind would you have a code snippet to share ? Thanks

Comment: Just do console.log(UserEntity) and see attributes or rawAttributes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224591/discussion-between-clement-s-and-anatoly).

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EUmu.png
rawAttributes have all the keys specified in models